# jQuery selectmenu change function triggers, but the code within wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code:

```
$("#department_select").change(function() {
            alert("trigger test");
            $("#county_select").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

I get the alert but the change wont be applied to $("#county_select").

Now if I put this without a function:

```
$("#county_select").prop("disabled", true);
```

It applies the change on page load. So that piece of code wont work within the selectmenu change event, even if I know that event works. I have no idea why?

EDIT: HTML part without the table structure

```
<select title="counties" name="counties[]" multiple="multiple" 
id="county_select" class="chosen-select" data-width="150px">
..bunch of php generated options from sql..
</select>

<select title="departments" name="departments[]" multiple="multiple" 
id="department_select" class="chosen-select" data-width="150px">
..some php generated options from sql..
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant HTML part as well?

Comment: Added the HTML of the select boxes

Comment: Well your code seems to be working : https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/dJQgYL?editors=1010 . The first selector does get grey and disabled when you use the second one.

Comment: Are you using the chosen-plugin? Maybe it changes some of the event-handling? Maybe check https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code working fine. I suppose you have not add your part of code inside `document.ready()`. Please try with

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#department_select").change(function() {
              alert("trigger test");
              $("#county_select").prop("disabled", true);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="counties" name="counties[]" multiple="multiple" 
id="county_select" class="chosen-select" data-width="150px">
<option>test 1</option>
</select>

<select title="departments" name="departments[]" multiple="multiple" 
id="department_select" class="chosen-select" data-width="150px">
<option>test 1</option>
<option>test 2</option>
</select>
```